# Movie with teenage alien girl living on Earth

Tags: story-identification, aliens

There was a movie that I remember watching in the early 90s, I think, that has been bugging me.

All I really remember is that the main female character, possibly with light brown hair, was a teenaged alien who ended up on Earth (possibly Southern California based on the weather) after her ship crashed, and there is a scene where she and a boy she meets run into a teacher and shatter a jar holding cow's eyes for a biology lab. She identifies one of the eyes as being from a blind cow, which the teacher was surprised by.  This happens at a high school, as the boy is a student there.  Weird bit to remember, but it stuck with me.

I thought it might be a Disney TV movie (my memory of watching it was as part of a Halloween season movie marathon that included The Worst Witch, which could have been Nickleodeon as well, I don't quite remember) but not according to Wikipedia's list of made for TV Disney movies from 1985-1993.

Comment: This is just a very wild guess (hence just a comment), but ... Disney, female teenager who is an alien, highschool setting, late 80s/early 90s ... while I cannot find any references to the particular cow's eyes occurrence and some other details you describe are not a complete hit, could this be the series [*Out of This World*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out_of_This_World_(TV_series))? It's a sitcom about a half-alien teenaged girl living in California, produced from 1987 to 1991, and at least in my place, it was shown on a channel that heavily focuses on (Disney-like) family entertainment.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/187324/water-wars-time-travel-tv-show (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 5):

I'm pretty sure it is a TV series, "[The Girl From Tomorrow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Girl_from_Tomorrow)", but yes it was shown on Nickelodeon like other non-American made TV series such as "The Tomorrow People" (the 90's version (not the recent remake or the 70's version)), where Nickelodeon had a tendency to show them when they didn't have enough US-made content.

> *The Girl from Tomorrow* is an Australian children's television series created by Film Australia. The series is based around Alana (Katharine Cullen), a girl from the year 3000. At the start of the series, she is kidnapped by Silverthorn, a criminal from the year 2500, and brought back in time to the year 1990.
>
> While in the year 1990, she befriends Jenny (Melissa Marshall), who helps Alana adapt to life in a time unfamiliar to her, and later helps her to return to her own time.
>
> A sequel series, The Girl from Tomorrow Part II: Tomorrow's End aired in 1991.

I distinctly remember the scene you are referring to and it is something that stuck with me as well. The scene is from when Jenny (and her Mother) take Alana to enroll her in Jenny's school and Jenny's Mum literally runs into the science teacher who has a box of eyes for a class experiment - episode 4, about 4 minutes in. You can watch the entire series  (or at least most of it) on YouTube.

> "This creature was blind"
> "Why do you say that?"
> "It has a cataract"

Comment: Maybe you could add more detail to show the OP that this is the film they're looking for.

Comment: Yes, please [edit] to add a better description of the movie, rather than just "You can look it up on google".

Comment: I hope that is better and that someone is able to answer my question as throughly.

Comment: And the line is in there at about 4:45 in of "This creature was blind" "Why do you say that?" "It has a cataract".

Answer (score 1):

I have been researching a similar movie and could never recall the movie name except that somewhere on the title, it said "Sapian".  Come to find out it's called *[Hyper Sapian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper_Sapien:_People_from_Another_Star)* released in 1986 which thought I recalled it to be a 90’s release.  Great childhood movie.

> One night, three aliens from the planet Taros — a young woman named Robyn, a girl named Tavy, and a furry three-eyed, three-armed creature named Kirbi — stow away on a spaceship headed for Earth, and land near Aladdin, Wyoming. The next morning, the aliens befriend a rancher's son named Dirt while he's out riding fences on his motorcycle. Robyn shows off her bike-riding skills, and the quartet go to visit Dirt's grandparents. After Kirbi beats Grandpa at poker, the creature drinks a can of gasoline. Later, Kirbi keeps feeding the goats even though Grandpa wants him to feed the chickens. Grandpa then shows Kirbi how to shoot Coors cans with a gun while he complains about how much the world has changed. Dirt forms a relationship with Robyn, learning that her hair changes color depending on exposure to sunlight and that she's come from a moonbase and was supposed to go back to her home planet, rather than coming to Earth. Dirt tries to keep his new friends a secret from the rest of his family, but things get complicated when other aliens come looking for the missing trio, Grandpa shows Kirbi to some old folks at the General Store, and a Senator arrives at the ranch for a barbecue.

Comment: Could you [edit] this to describe how it matches the description given in the question?